# Nagios Basic Configuration (for quick addition of new machines)

Tags: monitoring, nagios, nrpe, system-monitoring

I recently started to use Nagios to monitor about 25 servers (mainly virtual, with some standalone). Them majority of the servers (including the Nagios host itself) are running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, with a few running 12.04 LTS. Thus, I thought I could just utilize NRPE and be done with it.

Configuring NRPE has proven to be rather complex for me. For instance, for a simple check_disk command, I had to manually specify which partition to check by excluding every other partition/filesystem, as shown below:

```
command[check_disk]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_disk -w 57% -x /dev -x /run -x /run/lock -x /run/shm -x /run/user -x /sys/fs/cgroup
```

Otherwise my thresholds for warning and critical were immediately set off by sysfs, proc, or other partitions.

Then I took a look at the base service monitor that the Nagios host performs on itself. That is listed inside /usr/local/nagios/etc/localhost.cfg, and contains the following (I'm sorry! I don't understand why it won't properly format!)

```
define service{
    use                             local-service         ; Name of service template to use
    host_name                       localhost
    service_description             PING
check_command           check_ping!100.0,20%!500.0,60%
    }



define service{
    use                             local-service         ; Name of service template to use
    host_name                       localhost
    service_description             Root Partition
check_command           check_local_disk!20%!10%!/
    }




define service{
    use                             local-service         ; Name of service template to use
    host_name                       localhost
    service_description             Current Users
check_command           check_local_users!20!50
    }


define service{
    use                             local-service         ; Name of service template to use
    host_name                       localhost
    service_description             Total Processes
check_command           check_local_procs!250!400!RSZDT
    }



define service{
    use                             local-service         ; Name of service template to use
    host_name                       localhost
    service_description             Current Load
check_command           check_local_load!5.0,4.0,3.0!10.0,6.0,4.0
    }


define service{
    use                             local-service         ; Name of service template to use
    host_name                       localhost
    service_description             Swap Usage
check_command           check_local_swap!20!10
    }


define service{
    use                             local-service         ; Name of service template to use
    host_name                       localhost
    service_description             SSH
check_command           check_ssh
notifications_enabled       0
    }



define service{
    use                             local-service         ; Name of service template to use
    host_name                       localhost
    service_description             HTTP
check_command           check_http
notifications_enabled       0
    }
```

Which results in this on the dashboard:

[image: awesome]

This is PERFECT for me. This is exactly what I want every single host I add to show. Rather than messing around with custom commands, how exactly should I "copy" this to each host through the NRPE conf file so that I see all these specific services for each host I add? It's clear this is already here and already functions on the localhost. I'm struggling to wrap my head around the organization needed to make this happen.

Thank you for any and all advice.

Comment: Could your nagios server access all the remote systems via SSH?  Do you have any concerns about setting letting the nagios server connect to all the other via SSH?  You can make your client somewhat easier by using the `check_by_ssh` plugin instead of nrpe.

Comment: There are no issues with letting them SSH to each other, but ultimately the plugins are what matter to me. NRPE or otherwise, I'm finding it difficult to map out how I can replicate what the localhost monitors to the hosts themselves. I like what I see in the screenshot above, and I want it for each of my hosts. Even if I have to manually update each configuration file, that doesn't bother me; it's the layout and organization of the config file, both on the server side and on the host side that I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: The important thing to realize about nagios is the templating, and service/host groups can and will make configuration a lot easier.  So you setup commands, and services and assign them to a host group.  Then you simply set your host to be a member of that group possibly in the template for your host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not so long ago I wrote a really nice NRPE auto installer script which I believe can assist you if you edit it to suit your needs.
The script includes many built-in checks which are being added to each host's `nrpe.cfg` file.
Meaning, that you can configure the checks that are relevant to you and make sure that each host which is running the script will have them as well, that's about the client side.

A link to the script: [Here](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Utilities/NRPE-automatic-installation-for-CentOS-2FRHEL-5-2F6/details).

In regard to the server side (Nagios), You can install a Nagios-Configuration Manager such as NagioSQL for example which will help you manage your hosts and services in a more convenient way through a GUI.

More than that, In order to make sure that all your hosts have these checks you showed, simply create a service group which includes all these services (checks) you want to monitor and then just attach this service group to each host you monitor.

Let me tell you what I did in my company, I wanted to make sure that each server is monitored with the `check_load` check but since we have no hardware baseline in the company which means that each server has different specs and the `check_load` is calculated per cores/cpu's in the machine, I've added to the "Nagios_client" module in our Puppet server a `custom_fact` which identifies how many processors exist in a machine and configures the Nagios `check_load` accordingly.

So for example, let's say server1 has 4 cpu's, meaning that 2.8 load is ideal (0.7 per cpu).
Puppet through `facter` identifies the number of cpu's and then edits the server's `nrpe.cfg` like so:

```
command[check_load]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_load -w 2.9,3.0,3.1 -c 4.0,5.0,6.0
```

Then, in NagioSQL for example, you can use the "Import feature" which allows you to import `*.cfg` files which will be loaded to Nagios as Hosts and Services.
So you can create one `host.cfg` file and through a script duplicate it per host you want to monitor and just change the hostname/ip of each machine and it would take you another step into a more automatic configurations.

In my case for example, Puppet is able to understand that it is running for the first time on a machine and then also created the relevant `host.cfg` file in Nagios.

I believe that with Puppet + NagioSQL your Nagios administration would be a much easier task.

In regard to your difficulty with configuring any checks... You can always write your own script and configure Nagios to run it for you.
For example, let's take your `check_disk` command, it is a very rich command which allows you to display all kinds of data which is unnecessarily important to you.

So I've had the same issue with `check_procs` , another very rich command which gives you all kinds of data... which I didn't need, so I wrote a simple check script which does exactly what I need and configured it in Nagios.
Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script checks for running processes for mt.js and adb-server.js
# Script by Itai Ganot 2015 .
process="$1"
appname=$(basename $0)
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "Please specify a process to check"
    exit 1
fi
ps -ef | grep "$process" | egrep -v "grep|$appname" &>/dev/null
if [ "$?" -eq "0" ] ; then
    stat="OK"
    exitcode="0"
    msg="Process $process is running"
else
    stat="Critical"
    exitcode="2"
    msg="There are currently no running processes of $process"
fi
pid=$(ps -ef | grep "$process" | egrep -v "grep|$appname" | awk '{print $2}')
echo "$stat: $msg Process PID: $pid"
exit $exitcode
```

It gives me less information than the real `check_procs` but gives me just the information I need.

So to make things short, if your `check_disk` command gives you a hard time configuring it, then simply create your own script, that's the beauty of Nagios.

I hope I helped you.

Comment: This is wonderful! I need to fully read this (my Monday just began) and I'll let you know what I find. Thank you for taking the time to give me such a detailed answer, it is much appreciated!

Comment: Hello, I'd like to thank you again for your detailed answer. I ended up using a lot of your ideas to make my life a lot easier in configuring Nagios hosts. Cheers!

Comment: That's really nice to know :)

Answer (score 1):

You need some type of configuration management software to setup and install nrpe daemon on each remote host as well as deploy the configurations and ultimately your plugins.

May I suggest [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com/home) for this task.

https://github.com/bobmaerten/ansible-role-nagios-nrpe-server

Comment: Paid monitoring solutions are not an option for me, not now and unfortunately not in the future. What I'm looking for the is the simplest way to replicate the localhost monitoring plugin setup on each host, as the current localhost monitoring service list is exactly what I need for each host I monitor.

Comment: Who said anything about paid solutions? Configuration management tools like Ansible are open source.

Comment: Apologies. I didn't fully read your github link. This looks interesting, but with how long I've been working on this and the timeframe in which I'm expected to provide an example, I don't think I have enough time to understand Ansible. Perhaps as a weekend project. Thank you, though!

Comment: Probably a weekend project, ya.